# Contagem de Pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pessoal estou tentando fazer um sistema de contagem de paginas,que ele conta o total de paginas e qual pagina atual o usuario se encontra.

Eu consegui fazer a contagem total de pagina porem não estou conseguindo achar um modo para mostra a pagina atual dele ,tentei usar o metodo de position() mas nao consegui.

```
var arrMenuInterno = [
{ titulo: "Introdução",
    telas: [
        {arquivo: "ambev_VPO_gente_sld002.swf", tipo:""},
        {arquivo: "ambev_VPO_gente_sld005.swf", tipo:""},
        {arquivo: "ambev_VPO_gente_sld007.swf", tipo:""},
        {arquivo: "ambev_VPO_gente_sld009.swf", tipo:""},
        {arquivo: "ambev_VPO_gente_sld010.swf", tipo:""}

    ]
}
```

];

```
for(var i = 0;i < arrMenuInterno.length;i++){
            _totalTelas = arrMenuInterno[i].telas.length;

        }

        $("#qtdTelas").html(+ localizaTelaAtual + "</b> de <b>" + _totalTelas + "</b>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a atributo [Data](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) do HTML5 para armazenar os índices do seu array de páginas. Segue um exemplo de implementação.

```js
var arrMenuInterno = [
{ titulo: "Introdução",
    telas: [
        {arquivo: "ambev_VPO_gente_sld002.swf", tipo:""},
        {arquivo: "ambev_VPO_gente_sld005.swf", tipo:""},
        {arquivo: "ambev_VPO_gente_sld007.swf", tipo:""},
        {arquivo: "ambev_VPO_gente_sld009.swf", tipo:""},
        {arquivo: "ambev_VPO_gente_sld010.swf", tipo:""}
    ]
}]
 
function getNextContent(){
  var $conteudo = $("#conteudo");
  var titleIndex = $conteudo.data("titleIndex");
  var fileIndex = $conteudo.data("fileIndex") + 1;
  var content = arrMenuInterno[titleIndex].telas[fileIndex];
  var countDescription = " [" + fileIndex + " de " + arrMenuInterno[titleIndex].telas.length + "]";

  if (content !== undefined){
   $conteudo.data("fileIndex", fileIndex);
   var $span = $("<span></span>");
   $span.append(content.arquivo + countDescription);
   $("#conteudo").html($span);
  }
}

function getPreviousContent(){
  var $conteudo = $("#conteudo");
  var titleIndex = $conteudo.data("titleIndex");
  var fileIndex = $conteudo.data("fileIndex")  - 1;
  var content = arrMenuInterno[titleIndex].telas[fileIndex];
  var countDescription = " [" + fileIndex + " de " + arrMenuInterno[titleIndex].telas.length + "]";

  if (content !== undefined){
   $conteudo.data("fileIndex", fileIndex);
   var $span = $("<span></span>");
   $span.append(content.arquivo + countDescription);
   $("#conteudo").html($span);
  }
}
```

```css
.content {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#conteudo {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 150px;
}

span {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

<div class="content">
<div id="conteudo" data-title-index="0" data-file-index="0">
   <span>Introdução</span>
</div>
</div>

<a type="button" href="#" id="anterior" onclick="getPreviousContent()">Anterior</a>
<a type="button" href="#" id="proximo" onclick="getNextContent()">Próximo</a>
</div>
```